# How to write adjoin-set recursively in Lisp/scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, binary-search-tree

I'd like to write the following ex:

```
(adjoin-set 2 (adjoin-set 8 (adjoin-set 4 (adjoin-set 3 (adjoin-set 7 (adjoin-set 5 '()))))))
```

recursively.

My other code is as follows (from Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, 2nd ed.)

```
(define (entry tree) (car tree))
(define (left-branch tree) (cadr tree))
(define (right-branch tree) (caddr tree))
(define (make-tree entry left right)
  (list entry left right))


(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (cond ((null? set) (make-tree x '() '()))
        ((= x (entry set)) set)
        ((< x (entry set))
         (make-tree (entry set)
                    (adjoin-set x (left-branch set))
                    (right-branch set)))
        ((> x (entry set))
         (make-tree (entry set)
                    (left-branch set)
                    (adjoin-set x (right-branch set))))))
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
(define (bst list)
  (if (null? list) '())

  (bst (adjoin-set (cdr list) '())))
```

This doesn't work. How could I make this work?

I'd like to follow a similar approach as when making the calls manually, i.e., `(adjoin-set (car list) (next adjoint-set))`.

Comment: In your attempt, you're not doing anything with the result of `(if (null? list) '())`.  The `(bst (adjoin-set ...))` isn't the *else* part of your `if`.  Did you mean (and did you try) `(if (null? list) '() (bst (adjoin-set (cdr list) '())))`?

Comment: So I've tried (define (bst list) (if (null? list) '() (bst (adjoin-set (cdr list) '())))) but it doesn't seem to work. It returns nothing and seems to be stuck in an endless loop... hmm!

Answer (score 1):

First, rather than working a binary search tree for representing sets, I'll just use lists with no duplicate elements.  The point is that we'll write a method to adjoin a *single* element, and then figure out how to call it with repeatedly with multiple values and get the final result.  You'll still be able to apply this approach to your tree-based implementation.

#### Representing sets with lists containing no duplicates

If we represent sets by lists with no duplicates, then a single **adjoin** just takes an element and a list and returns the list if the element is already in the list, or a new list created from the new element and the old list, if the list doesn't contain it.  So, **adjoin** isn't too hard:

```
(define (member? element list)
  (cond
    ((null? list) #f)
    ((eqv? (car list) element) #t)
    (else (member? element (cdr list)))))

(define (adjoin element set)
  (if (member? element set)
      set
      (cons element set)))
```

This is counterpart of what you've already got with **adjoin-set** from SICP.

#### Performing more than one operation

Now, if you want to be able to adjoin a bunch of elements onto some initial value, you're performing a *reduction*, or *fold*.  There are lots of variant implementations of **reduce** or **fold** (and **foldr**, **foldl**, etc.), but a quick and simple left-associative version is:

```
(define (reduce function list initial-value)
  (if (null? list)
      initial-value
      (reduce function
              (cdr list)
              (function (car list) initial-value))))
```

Now, you can **reduce** your **adjoin** function over a list of elements of and get the final result:

```
(define (adjoin* elements set)
  (reduce adjoin elements set))
```

Here are two examples that adjoin a bunch of elements to some preexisting sets. In the first case, the set is the empty set.  In the second case, it's the set **(1 2 3 4)**.  Of course, to make this work with your code, those initial sets will need to be tree-based sets.

```
(display (adjoin* '(5 7 3 4 8 2) '()))
;;=> (2 8 4 3 7 5)

(display (adjoin* '(5 7 3 4 8 2) '(1 2 3 4)))
;;=> (8 7 5 1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

I can get a list just fine, problem is that I need it as a binary search tree as such:

input: (bst (list 5 7 3 4 8 2))

output: (5 (3 (2 () ()) (4 () ())) (7 () (8 () ())))

so that it retains its' binary search tree property which will enable me to do further stuff on the output.

Comment: @Lennart Yes;  what I was trying to illustrate is that once you can insert a single element into a binary search tree and return the new tree, all you need to do is `(reduce insert-single-element-into-tree elements-to-insert initial-tree)`.